# MySQL Process List has too many process. Is it normal?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, web-services, connection

I created an Android app like social media app. I'm using ASP.NET web services for fetching data with JSON or process data like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE. And I'm using MySQL database.

Number of active users is about 2,5k and daily average is 1,5k.

Anyway, when I control process list with "show processlist;" on phpMyAdmin , there are a lot of process; some processes has Sleep command value. So this situation gets errors like decreasing app speed and some times "max_user_connections".

So, I closed all connections after completing process of database on Web Service, but still have that issue or errors.

```
[WebMethod]
public string ABC(int x, string y)
{
    using (con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
    {
        List<Profile> result= new List<Profile>();
        result.Add(new Profile
        {
            posts= ""
        });

        List<ClassA> resultA= new List<ClassA>();

        query= "SELECT COUNT(FollowId) FROM Followings WHERE FUserId = " + x;
        con.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string count = "0";
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            count = dr[0].ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();

        query= "SELECT COUNT(FollowId) FROM Followings WHERE FollowingUserId = " + x;
        con.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string count2 = "0";
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            count2 = dr[0].ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();

        query= "SELECT .... FROM Posts WHERE UserId = " + x+ " ORDER BY PostId DESC LIMIT 30";
        con.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int i;
        int count3 = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            count3++;
            i = 0;
            resultA.Add(new ClassA
            {
                postId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[i]),
                postUrl = dr[++i].ToString(),
                ... = Convert.ToInt32(dr[++i])

            });
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();

        string json = "";
        if (resultA.Count > 0)
        {
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultA);
        }

        result[0].posts = json;


        json = "";
        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        }
        return json;
    }

}
```

It's any example of my web methods. Where do I mistake ?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: i hope this isn't live code because this is full of SQL injection leaks..

Comment: It is live code. How am I optimizing this code ? I cannot understand your comment.

Comment: i assume you don't know the term [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)? .. You need to solve it with prepared statements.

Comment: I cannot understand what about you say. 
My problem is , on MySQL a lot of process which has Sleep command.